# How to search for pages by name in Facebook Graph API with least amount of calls using Python?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

I have a list of football team names `my_team_list = ['Bayern Munich', 'Chelsea FC', 'Manchester United', ...]` and try to search for their official Facebook page to get their `fan_count` using the Python `facebook-api`. This is my code so far:

```
club_list = []

for team in my_team_list:
    data = graph.request('/pages/search?q=' + team[0])

    for i in data['data']:
        likes = graph.get_object(id=i['id'], fields='id,name,fan_count,is_verified')
        if likes['is_verified'] is True:
            club_list.append([team[0],likes['name'],likes['fan_count'],likes['id']])
```

However, because my list contains over 3000 clubs, with this code I will get the following rate limit error:

`GraphAPIError: (#4) Application request limit reached`

How can I reduce the calls to get more than one club's page per call (e.g. batch calls?)

Comment: Batching does not change how the number of requests is counted. You need to make less requests, resp. spread them out over a larger amount of time.

Comment: OK. But how can I get the X-App-Usage header information in the `facebook-api` library for python? If I have such information I could use it to perform `time.sleep()` when a defined threshold is reached to wait for the next run

Answer (score 0):

As the comment on the OP states, batching will not save you. You need to be actively watching the rate limiting:

"All responses to calls made to the Graph API include an X-App-Usage HTTP header. This header contains the current percentage of usage for your app. This percentage is equal to the usage shown to you in the rate limiting graphs. Use this number to dynamically balance your call load to avoid being throttled."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting#application-level-rate-limiting

On your first run through, you should save all of the valid page ids so in the future you can just query those ids instead of doing a search.

Comment: Yes, I am already saving the ids. Do you know of any function in the python `facebook-api` library that returns the X-App-Usage header? Because I cannot find any. When I have such information I can use `time.sleep()` to wait for the next run.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, we use the php sdk